# file listing system-wide

Tags: filesystem, xfce, find

I am encountering a strange problem on my local machine. I am a developer and I am working with SAP/Hybris. This environment provides an ant build script which even builds the entire web application.
I am encountering errors concerning the way how the classpath is build together. It seems that the order of the included JAR-Libs (which are included by the environment itself and I do not changed anything in that ant/pom files) differs from the order of the classpath of all other machines (colleagues or integration machines). Some libs are included too early.

I also noticed that the result of the command find -name "*.jar" returns a list of files that differs from the list that the command returns of a laptop of a colleague from mine (we both have Ubuntu with XFCE4).

So the question I have is:

Is there a way to define how the files are listed system-wide? Does this error depends on the file system and the way how the files are listed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the order files are seen from application view are through the different PATH variables.
PATH defines in what order directories are searched for executabels to execute.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH defines directories and order to search for libaries when compiling and linking a program.

CLASSPATH (and --classpath argument that is searched before CLASSPATH variable) defines the order Java class'es are searched.

There might be other PATH variables too, but their stories are the same.

In what order `find` lists files has no impact on the above mentioned PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned the environment I develop with is SAP/Hybris. This environment provides ant build scripts and libraries  and normally you do not need to change these scripts and the way they build, compile and solve the dependencies. These ones are searched from its root folder. The variables (as classpath) are not set manually during the build process.

I have checked my PATH variable and i cannot see anything "wrong" in that (I will compare it with the one of my colleagues).

The variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is unknown and unset. I think it is not used at all.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH was just an example on an other PATH variable. If you can't find where CLASSPATH is set, you might look to a SAP/Hybris support site.

Comment: yes i already asked there...... I am waiting for an answer !)